# Remove only one specified directory recursively from a folder (Linux)

Tags: linux, shell, rm

My question is pretty quick to explain, I don't know about the solution.

I have a folder always containing 3 folders that can themself contained others folder. I would like to be able to remove only a specific folder from all 3 firsts folders. Here how I picture the thing :

For example here I would like with a single command to remove all folder named `Folder 1` under the `User` folder (if it's possible, if not using a shell script could do the trick)

```
> User_folder
     > Folder_A
         > Folder_1 --> To remove
         > Folder_2
         > Folder_3
         > Folder_4
     > Folder_B
         > Folder_1 --> To remove
         > Folder_5
         > Folder_6
         > Folder_7
     > Folder_C
         > Folder_1 --> To remove
         > Folder_2
         > Folder_4
         > Folder_5
```

Comment: `find /path/to/User_folder -type d -name "Folder_1" -delete`?

Comment: Hi, those are not my real folder names it was for explanation purpose only. There are no spaces inside them, I can edit the post.

Comment: Okay, works the same either way. Note: this question is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) since it isn't about a specific programming problem. It is more "How do I delete ....".

Comment: If all the `Folder_1`s are at the same level then `rmdir User_folder/*/Folder_1`.

Comment: Both works fine, thank you. I didn't know about those StackExchange site, will look their next time !